# Android : Widget - Null pointer Exception when using setOnclickPendingIntent on the remoteviews?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, android-pendingintent

I got a Widget ( appwidgetprovider + service)
This service updates the UI basically like this :

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
//doing some stuff like which works without any errors : 
views.setTextViewText(R.id.Time, time);

// Here I'm calling a static method that set pendingIntent on different ID  :
// With it : Null Pointer Exception, without not.
views = HomeWidgetUtils.setPendingIntentForAllWidgetSubView(context, views);

//update AppWidgetProvider : 
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context, WDWidgetProvider.class);
manager.updateAppWidget(widget, views);
```

So Everything works fine without using my static method that set PendingIntent to id, 
setPendingIntentForAllWidgetSubView
Here is the code :

```
public static RemoteViews setPendingIntentForAllWidgetSubView(Context context,RemoteViews rv){
    rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Widget, HomeWidgetUtils.getPendingIntentonActivity(context, WeatherForecast.class));

rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.globallayout, HomeWidgetUtils.getPendingIntentonActivity(context, TabActivity01.class));
    return rv;
}

public static  PendingIntent getPendingIntentonActivity(Context context,Class C) {
    Intent intentleft = new Intent(context, C);
    intentleft.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intentleft,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

If I use it , here is the NPE I Got : ( line 283 is related to manager.updateAppWidget(widget, views); )

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.RemoteViews$SetOnClickPendingIntent.writeToParcel(RemoteViews.java:131)
at android.widget.RemoteViews.writeToParcel(RemoteViews.java:1003)
at com.android.internal.appwidget.IAppWidgetService$Stub$Proxy.updateAppWidgetIds(IAppWidgetService.java:374)
at android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetManager.java:246)
at fr.cdcorp.homewidget.clock.ClockWidgetService.update(ClockWidgetService.java:283)
at fr.cdcorp.homewidget.clock.ClockWidgetService$1.onReceive(ClockWidgetService.java:312)
at  android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:892)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Furthermore, I'm sure widget and views are not null in  manager.updateAppWidget(widget, views) instruction.
So What Am I doing Wrong when setting pendingIntent ????

Any Helps would be appreciate !!!
CD.

Working solution (according to post author):

```
public static PendingIntent getPendingIntentonActivity(Context context,Class C) { 
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent = null; 
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(
         Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, C); 
    mIntent.setComponent(cn); 
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, 
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
}
```

Comment: Check wether you have declared your WeatherForecast.class and TabActivity01.class in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`:

```
public static  PendingIntent getPendingIntentonActivity(Context context,Class C) {
    Intent intentleft = new Intent(context, C);
    intentleft.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intentleft.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intentleft,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: thank you, but nothing change. NPE again... really don't know why it failed.

Comment: Which android version is this on?

Comment: 2.2 apilevel 8 , but It seems many of users get this with my latest update. What is really strange is that works like a charm on my HTC Desire 2.2 ... So I can reproduce issue with emulator 2.2 api level 8.. and others api levels too.

Comment: hum....if I build and set pendingIntent directly before updateappwidget call like this :

Comment: Intent intentleft = new Intent(context, WeatherForecast.class);
         intentleft.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//         intentleft.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Widget,PendingIntent.getActivity(......It works .... wow Android is strange sometimes...

Comment: Odd. The error occurs because `HomeWidgetUtils.getPendingIntentonActivity` is returning null, instead of a valid `PendingIntent`. So I would check that the `WeatherForecast.class` and the `TabActivity01.class` have `<activity>` entries in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I check AndroidManifest.xml and nothing is wrong. Furthermore, creating on the fly PendingIntent on these activity  works ....(see my last comment) ... maybe it is not allowed to create pendingIntent in static method ;-) ...this is ODD, you're right ;-)

Comment: How about if you use `R.id.globallayout`, does that work too?

Comment: If I change getPendingIntentonActivity(Context context,Class C) this way, It works :

Comment: public static  PendingIntent getPendingIntentonActivity(Context context,Class C) {     
       PendingIntent mPendingIntent = null;
       Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
       ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, C);
       mIntent.setComponent(cn);
          return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);     
 }

Comment: I 'm going to use this one. Too much time wasted on this issue. So thank U so much Femi for your help.

Comment: Glad to help, and that is useful to know that it needs a `ComponentName` as well.